# unity azure mobile services for Windows 8 and Android

Tags: android, azure, windows-8, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to use azure to allow me to make an online leader board for my game , now i followed the bit-rave tutorial steps  and when i run the script off my computer it writes to the azure database and reads from it to all perfect, but when i put the app onto android or windows phone they both seem to not go into the Read Handler method, can anyone help me as i really would like to get this working on my game. i have used the method from bit-rave website and it does seem to work when running from unity editor but nothing is working from mobile devices on both platforms?

EDIT: so i read somewhere my error was because i was missing thr RestSharp.WindowsPhone.dll in the plugins folder so i found a version online and inserted into the folder and all these erros came up so im guessing the file needs to be relevant to this package?

```
Error building Player: Exception: Failed to run reference rewriter with command "--target="Temp/StagingArea\Assembly-CSharp.dll" --framework="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0,C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries,C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WP8Support\Players\ARM\master" --platform="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Windows MetaData\Windows.winmd" --support="Temp\StagingArea\WinRTLegacy.dll" --winmdrefs="" --system=System --dbg=pdb --alt=System.Net;System.Net.Sockets,System.Net;System.Xml.Serialization;System.ComponentModel,System.Windows;System.Threading,mscorlib". [Temp/StagingArea\Assembly-CSharp.dll]
Catastrophic failure while running rrw: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'RestSharp.WindowsPhone, Version=104.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.RewriteContext.RewriteResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.RewriteTypeReferences.Visit(TypeReference type, String referencingEntityName)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.ReferenceDispatcher.Visit(MethodReference method, String referencingEntityName)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.ReferenceDispatcher.DispatchMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.ReferenceDispatcher.DispatchMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.ReferenceDispatcher.DispatchMethods(TypeDefinition type)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.ReferenceDispatcher.Dispatch()
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.RewriteOperation.Execute(RewriteContext context)
   at Unity.ReferenceRewriter.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Unity and running on the desktop vs deploying to a device but are your Android / Windows Phone apps requiring / using the Internet permission?

Comment: well this is the thing it mentions adding a line into the android manifest but i am using unity so i cant find any manifest file

Comment: ok you was right with the android i gave it internet permissions and now it works but now for windows when u go to build i get an error , i have emailed bitrave hopefully they get back to me asap

Comment: I'll add an answer for it to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

When moving from the desktop version to a mobile (Android / WinPhone) make sure you've enabled Internet permissions as that has to be explicitly required.